# Remove specific character from string

Tags: python, string

I want to create a function that takes a line from a .txt file and remove double-spaces, but every thing i tried, and found on the internet, removes every instance of the character i want to remove or just the first instance.

```
    def reduceWhitespace():
        my_file = open("Teste.txt", "r")
        new_line = ""
        old_line = my_file.readline()
        empty_char = ""

        for char in range(len(old_line)):
            if old_line [char] == " ":
                if old_line [char + 1] == " ":
                    new_line = old_line.replace(old_line [char], empty_char)

        print (new_line)
        my_file.close()

    reduceWhitespace()
```

The output should be the line with no double-spaces:

"This line  has extra  space characters"

But instead it outputs the string with no spaces:

"Thislinehasextraspacecharacters"

Comment: `new_line = ' '.join(old_line.split())`.

Comment: it would be good if you provide a sample string and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

below code will convert multiple space into one space: (`replace_double_space()` function will convert multiple space in string into 1)

```
def replace_double_space(line):
    while "  " in line:
        line = line.replace("  ", " ")
    return line

my_file = open("Teste.txt", "r")
line = my_file.readline()
print ("before: ", line)

new_line = replace_double_space(line)
print ("after: ", new_line)
```

execution result:

```
PS E:\> python .\test.py
before:  This line has extra   space   characters
after:  This line has extra space characters
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
x="aa//a//aa//aa/a//a"
x=x.replace("//","/",x.count("//"))
print(x)
```

output look like this: aa/a/aa/aa/a/a

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in replace function.
For example,

```
str = 'A  line with  single  and double spaces'
str = str.replace('  ', '')
print(str)
```

This would output `'Aline withsingleand double spaces'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just replace them until done, you risk looping back through the line many times. Here is a generator based solution:

```
def singlespacer(s):
    last = None
    for c in s:
        if c == ' ' and last == ' ':
            continue
        last = c
        yield c
    
s = 'This  line  has       extra       spaces'

print (''.join(singlespacer(s)))
```